# proc sql function to find mulitple LIKE matches?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm having trouble with a LIKE function in proc sql.

```
    PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE NAMES_IDS AS 
        SELECT DISTINCT
        T1.*
        ,T2.NAMES
        ,T2.NAME_ID
            FROM WORK.table1 T1
                LEFT JOIN data.table2 T2 ON T2.NAMES like T1.NAMES1
;QUIT;
```

I have several names in t2, lets say for example theres John 1, John 2, John 3, John 4, etc and in t1.Names1 there is %John%

proc sql is just pulling in the first match, John 1 and its associated ID, and applying it to all the data in T1, instead of duplicated a match for all matching names (this is what I want to achieve).

So the end table would have something like

```
COLUMN A      COLUMN B
John          John 1
John          John 2
John          John 3
John          John 4
```

But instead, what I get is:

```
COLUMN A      COLUMN B
John          John 1
John          John 1
John          John 1
John          John 1
```

Hopefully this makes some sort of sense...

Comment: you are forgetting %% in your like statement, isn't that the problem?

Comment: `LIKE` without wildcards, `%`, should just use `=`.

Comment: the % is in the table already "in t1.Names1 there is %John%"

Comment: Please show current data and results (not just desired results).

Comment: Added to end of have vs want, i'm not sure of a better way to post the actual data output

Comment: Instead of storing the `%` in the table, simply put it on the join syntax; `on T2.NAMES like cats('%',T1.NAMES,'%)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, I added TRIM to my code and I guess there may have been some erroneous spaces somewhere because that seems to fix my issue.  Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Correct, the feature of SAS character values having trailing spaces out to the variable's length can interfere with some intuitions for certain string functions and comparators.  Read the reference documentation at https://support.sas.com/en/documentation.html when struggling :)